# What does the error "single-row subquery returns more than one row" means and how to fix it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query for all movies that have a higher score than a randomly selected movie score. I don't understand the error to fix my query.

*List the titles of movies that have a higher score than some movie in the database.

(Don't hardcode "some" movie as any specific movie such as "Titanic".)*

```
SELECT TITLE FROM MOVIE
WHERE SCORE > (SELECT SCORE FROM MOVIE);
```

Comment: The question doesn't make obvious sense to me.  I'm not sure if the goal is "Randomly choose a movie and show all movies with a higher score than that randomly chosen movie" or "Show all movies that have a higher score than any movie in the database (i.e. return every movie except for those with the lowest score)".

Comment: I'm trying to query for all movies that have a higher score than a randomly selected movie score. However, I get that error and I'm trying to understand what it means.

Comment: [ORA-01427](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903): **Cause**: The outer query must use one of the keywords ANY, ALL, IN, or NOT IN to specify values to compare because the subquery returned more than one row.

**Action**: Use ANY, ALL, IN, or NOT IN to specify which values to compare or reword the query so only one row is retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Halim Saad-Rached mentions in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71200229/1509264), `SELECT SCORE FROM MOVIE` is returning multiple rows and you are then trying to compare each row in the outer query to multiple rows in the inner query.

> I'm trying to query for all movies that have a higher score than a randomly selected movie score.

You need to find a single random movie rather than all movies.

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT TITLE
FROM   MOVIE
WHERE  SCORE > (SELECT SCORE
                FROM   MOVIE
                ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
                FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
               );
```

Or, in earlier versions:

```sql
SELECT TITLE
FROM   MOVIE
WHERE  SCORE > (SELECT score
                FROM   (
                  SELECT SCORE
                  FROM   MOVIE
                  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
                )
                WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
               );
```

or, using analytic functions to only query the table once:

```sql
SELECT title
FROM   (
  SELECT title,
         score,
         MIN(score)
           KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(), ROWNUM)
           OVER ()
           AS random_score
  FROM   MOVIE
)
WHERE  score > random_score;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c4636859c158ec5169fabf9d28357cf9)*

Answer (score 2):

The sub-query `SELECT SCORE FROM MOVIE` does not return a random score of a movie in other words a scalar but a list of scores.
You can't compare a scalar to the left of the > to a list at its right (the result of the sub-query). This is syntactically wrong.
You can correct this in many different ways. It depends on what you want.
Here are some working examples with > operator:

```
SELECT TITLE FROM MOVIE
WHERE SCORE > (SELECT MAX(SCORE) FROM MOVIE)
```

```
SELECT TITLE FROM MOVIE
WHERE SCORE > (SELECT MIN(SCORE) FROM MOVIE)
```

```
SELECT TITLE FROM MOVIE
WHERE SCORE > ALL (SELECT SCORE FROM MOVIE)
```

```
SELECT TITLE FROM MOVIE
WHERE SCORE > ANY (SELECT SCORE FROM MOVIE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation, and for the examples! It def helps to understand the error to fix what I'm doing wrong. haha